# cannot boot ubuntu with new kernel

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, kernel, vmware

My host operating system is Windows 7. 
I have installed vmware over it. And was running ubuntu 10.04LTS using vmware.

But today out of curiosity, i downloaded new kernel 3.10.1 compiled it and installed it using commands:
make menuconfig, make -j32,make modules_install, make install

Here after installation i couldn't find initrd image in /boot location, so i copied a initrd image from another system over which i earlier installed 3.10.1 kernel.

And then i modified my grub.cfg, so that it could have a entry for new kernel.

But after restart, i am only seeing a blank screen over vmware and nothing else.

Could somebody point out what should i do now to recover my system.
Is my ubuntu OS is 10.04 and i have installed 3.10.1 is the issue or initrd copied from another machine has resulted in this problem

Comment: Any particular reason why you didn't just download kernel 3.11 or 3.12 from Ubuntu's kernel mainline repository? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Are you saying that kernel version 3.10.1 is causing this issue, because this kernel is working fine over my another machine(that machine is dual boot. It's unlike to my machine in problem, in that machine ubuntu was running over virtual environment).



I am guessing that installing 3.10.1 over ubuntu 10.04LTS could be the issue(3.10.1 installed over ubuntu 12.04LTS is working fine-->my another machine).



Another issue which i could think of is manual changing of grub.cfg.

Answer (score 0):

This might the solution to your problem! You might want to do some research over this problem by looking here at ask ubuntu. The next solution toward this problem would by using the program Grub Customizer! Good luck!